# How to access an object in a list of objects?

Tags: c#

I am implementing `Put` method in ASP.NET Web API. 

How can I access the object using `quotes[id]`?

```
public void Put(int id, [FromBody]Quote quote)
{
    quotes[id] = quote;
}
```

Comment: well... what and where is `quotes`? also: threading is very important - I *think* this is likely to hurt you...

Comment: I'd rather use a dictionary for this task.

Comment: I think qoutes  is List<Quote> and instead of assigning items to list, why don't you passing the list to Put method... simplify your code...and also simplify what you want to achieve ? ....

Comment: Quote is the class name , quote is the object we are passing from body, quotes is the list. My question is how we are able to put the quote object in quotes list using above code, can we access the object using quotes[id]???